# javascript / jquery - page is jerking while setting scrolltop

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar, scrolltop

I am using a light-box in which I am having some trouble with jquery `scrolltop()` function.
When light box opens it hides the document's scroll bar if it has any and save the vertical scroll position in a variable and when it closes, it brings back the scroll bar of the document and sets the scroll bar to it's old position. here's the code :

```
            $('html').css({
                'overflow-y' : 'auto'
            });
            $('html').scrollTop(org_scrolltop);
```

In this situation `scrollTop` function doesn't work at all. so I tried `setTimeout` function to set the scroll position. here's the code :

```
            $('html').css({
                'overflow-y' : 'auto'
            });
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('html').scrollTop(org_scrolltop);
            },10);
```

Now it works but page is jerking every now and then. I also tried `animate()` function but in vain.

What probably happening is that first the browser is setting the scroll bar to its default position i.e. 0 when I am setting the `overflow-y` to `auto` and after that `$('html').scrollTop(org_scrolltop);` this line of code is being executed. And in this process the page jerks.

I want to know is there any clean way to do it, I mean without using `setTimeout`. Any idea's will be very helpful.

Comment: "And in this process the page jerks off" -- phrasing!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 1000);
```

Obviously change the 0 to the position you with to scroll to, and change the 1000 to however long you want the scrolling to take.

Comment: hey Matt, i tried that too but the problem with animate function is that you have to wait for 1000 or ** milliseconds before it sets the scroll bar position and i don,t want that. And if i try to set the animation time to less then either the page jerks or it doesn't work at all.